# JS Masonry and Google Web Fonts Trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, typekit

I'm using Masonry in a layout I'm making and the layout is broken due to my use of Google Webfonts.  However, everything I've tried doesn't work. The Masonry code won't even fire up.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javscript">
var $container;

function triggerMasonry() {
  // don't proceed if $container has not been selected
  if ( !$container ) {
    return;
  }
  // init Masonry
  $container.masonry({
  itemSelector: '.omni-notify'
  });
}
// trigger masonry on document ready
$(function(){
  $container = $('#omni-content');
  triggerMasonry();
});

// trigger masonry when fonts have loaded
WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: [ 'Arvo:400,700:latin', 'Open+Sans::latin' ]
    }
  });
    </script>
```

This is the above code. It's a mess, but can someone show me how it's done?

Comment: Indent your code properly and then it won't be such a mess

Comment: @Bojangles Cool, but the presentation of the code isn't what I need help with

Comment: No, but it'll fix the "it's a mess" part of your question